# How to count occurrences of all the words in all the files of a directory? But with count incremented only once per word per file

Tags: bash, count, directory, command, cpu-word

I have already asked a similar question but people misunderstood what i was asking. I was asking how to generate a list of every word with a word count incremented only once per word per file.

fore example, I have a directory with 10 files , i want to generate a list of words using bash commands which says a value of 1-10 depending on how many files they appear in.

eg.

```
10 The
10 and
8 bash
7command
6 help....
ect.
```

I already know that `grep -l word *|wc -l` will search for a single word but i want to create a list of all words.

Is there a way to combine that with  `tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]' | tr -d '[:punct:]'` so that words with capital letters aren;t duplicated and puntuation is removed?

Answer (score 3):

Perform the following steps on each file:

1. Remove punctuation: `tr -d '[:punct:]'
2. Convert to lowercase and put one word per line: `tr 'A-Z ' 'a-z\n'`
3. Remove duplicate words: `sort -u`

Then concatenate all these results, and count the occurrences of each word: `sort | uniq -c`

So the full script will look like:

```
for file in *; do
    tr -d '[:punct:]' < "$file" | tr '[A-Z] ' '[a-z]\n' | sort -u
done | sort | uniq -c
```

Comment: Thank you, sorry if this seems like a stupid question but i'm very new to bash commands, but how exactly would i type that into terminal to recieve my results?

Comment: You would type exactly what I wrote, or put it into a shell script.

Comment: Yeah that's what I meant, how would I put this into a shell script?

Comment: Put it in a file that begins with `#!/bin/bash`, make it executable, and run it. This is basic shell scripting.

Answer (score 3):

if these are our files

```
$ cat file1
hello world
$ cat file2
the quick brown 
fox etc
$ cat file3
HELLO BROWN FOX
```

Then

```
grep -o '[[:alpha:]]\+' * | sed 's/:.*/\L&/' | sort -u | cut -d: -f2 | sort | uniq -c
      2 brown
      1 etc
      2 fox
      2 hello
      1 quick
      1 the
      1 world
```

- `grep` -  extracts sequences of alphabetic characters and prefixes each word with the filename and a colon
- `sed` - converts the word to lowercase, but not the filename (to differentiate between "file1" and "File1")
- `sort -u` - so that a word only appears once per file
- `cut` - remove the filename from the output
- `sort | uniq -c` - do the counting

Comment: This doesn't cover the punctuation part of the OPs request. Or rather, it does, but it does so by splitting `can't` into `can` and `t`.

Comment: Warning: `\L` is a GNU extension to `sed`.

Comment: This only half works for me unfortunately but I don't know why. Get a lot of words not counted and have a value of 1 such as the and and, which should be 10.

Answer (score 1):

An awk solution.

```
awk '
# Clear the "a" array for each new file.
FNR==1 {split("", a)}

{
    # Remove all punctuation.
    gsub(/[[:punct:]]*/, "")

    # Walk over each field.
    for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
        # Lowercase each word.
        word=tolower($i)

        # If we have not yet seen this word in this file then add it to our count.
        if (!a[word]) {
            words[word]++
        }

        # Store that we have now seen this word in this file.
        a[word]++
    }
}

END {
    # Loop over all the words and print out the counts.
    for (word in words) {
        print word, words[word]
    }
}' *
```

A lua solution (to get per-file as well as total counts). (You could do this in awk too but it would require a lot more looping since awk arrays aren't two-dimensional.)

```
local fmap = {}
local wmap = {}

for _, file in ipairs(arg) do
    if file ~= arg[0] then
        for line in io.lines(file) do
            line = line:gsub("%p*", "")
            line = line:gsub("%u*", string.lower)
            for word in line:gmatch("%w+") do
                fmap[file] = fmap[file] or {}
                fmap[file][word] = (fmap[file][word] or 0) + 1

                wmap[word] = (wmap[word] or 0) + 1
            end
        end
    end
end
print("# count by word")
for word, count in pairs(wmap) do
    print(count, word)
end
for file, wtab in pairs(fmap) do
    print("# count by word by file for "..file)
    for word, count in pairs(wtab) do
        print(count, word)
    end
end
```

Comment: The apostrophe in the comment is ending the awk script argument. Take a look at the syntax highlighting.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks. Added the comments in the edit box here didn't think about that.